# My tire sidewall was damaged. Chunk taken out. Can I repair and keep or need to replace?

Tags: tires, repair, damage, sidewall

I just noticed a chunk of tire hanging on my sidewall and a large abrasion to the rim. The height is 1.5 inch and width is 1in. The tires were just purchased 2 months**strong text** ago. If I have to replace the tire i will but I would prefer to get mileage from them... any advice? I am driving a Chevy Suburban ltx with Advantage T/A Sport LT tires by BF Goodrich. Tire size is 285/45/R22

Thank you!

Comment: **Each time I try to post a picture it says my image file size is too large?

Comment: https://photos.app.goo.gl/4X15RkzZm7Lkek3w5

Comment: For everyone’s safety, just replace it. Internal damage is not visible and can be catastrophic.

Comment: This question is off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most of the damaged tire questions that appear on the site the answer is replace the tire. The side wall is the thinnest part of the tire. The extent of the damage inside the tire is an unknown. While the tire is off ask them to inspect the wheel and try to remove the sharp edges of the damage.